# Dijkstra's Algorithm Concepts and Coding Problems

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra

### Question Updated

I am currently working on implementing Dijkstra's Algorithm in Python, I have looked at other questions here regarding the algorithm and none seem to fit what I am looking for.

Currently my program reads two text files, one containing a network routing diagram network.txt (basically the route costs).

```
0,2,4,1,6,0,0
2,0,0,0,5,0,0
4,0,0,0,0,5,0
1,0,0,0,1,1,0
6,5,0,1,0,5,5
0,0,5,1,5,0,0
0,0,0,0,5,0,0
```

and one containing the desired route (route.txt)

```
B>F
```

The Network Routing Table:
(Each Line Is a Node and Its Links so node A is linked to B, C, D and E)

```
      A  B  C  D  E  F  G

A    [0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0]
B    [2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
C    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]
D    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
E    [6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5]
F    [0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0, 0]
G    [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
```

Nodes On The Network:
([Structure] PreviousNode, DistanceFromSource, Visited)

```
A    [-1, 1000000000, False]
B    [-1, 1000000000, False]
C    [-1, 1000000000, False]
D    [-1, 1000000000, False]
E    [-1, 1000000000, False]
F    [-1, 1000000000, False]
G    [-1, 1000000000, False]
```

I kind of understand Dijkstra's Algorithm but using the two data structures I have, combined with having to write it in Python I don't have a clue where to go from here because I am unable to get my head round how to do this not knowing the language.

I have some very basic "pseudocode" to what I need to do next

> - 3 - Examine all the unvisited neighbours of the current node and calculate
>   their tentative distances from the starting node, overwriting the
>   existing distance if the new value is lower
> - 4 - Mark current node as visited (will not be examined again)
> - 5 - If not at destination and unvisited node exists go to the unvisited node with the smallest > distance from initial node and make it the current node, otherwise end
> - 6 - Go back to 3

Is anyone able to assist me with translating that "pseudocode" into code or even more meaningful pseudocode would be great as I am struggling with this

Comment: I don't know python. Still, If I were you, I would try separating the vocabulary of your specific problem from the algorithm, i.e. separate the details of how you get the data from actually using it.
Dijkstra's algorithm actually wants to know edge weights, not how you got those weights. So, write a pseudo code of Dijkstra's and then feed it the information it wants. HTH

Comment: "complicated versions using graphs etc" -- Dijkstra's algo is an algorithm on graphs, so understanding those is pretty fundamental to getting a good grasp on Dijkstra's.

Answer (score 2):

Use native python "links" between the objects, e.g.:

```
edges = {1: set([2,3,4]), 2: set([1,5]), ....}
costs = {(1, 2): 99.3, (1, 3): 127.77, ...}
```

There's no need to create your own classes for such simple problem.

Watch this for inspiration:

http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1530/pycon-2010-mastering-team-play

Comment: better yet, frozenset() instead of tuple on line 2.